# Translate the messages that come from the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, vuejs2, translation

I am using a hybrid application with vuejs and ruby on rails, I want to translate the error messages that come to me from the server, for the titles I could easily do them with a method but for the error messages I don't know how to translate them.

[image]

these are my errors taken from the server, as you can see the title of the error I managed to translate it, but the message I don't know how to do. For example End date i want to translate the message.

my code to get the errors:

```html
    <div v-if="getDataError">
          <div v-for="(_errors, key) in getDataError">
            <b-alert
                v-for="error in _errors"
                show
                variant="danger"
            >
              <h2>{{ formatKey(key) }} :</h2>
              <li>{{ error }}</li>
            </b-alert>
          </div>
        </div>
```

my method to translate the title message :

```js
methods: {
    formatKey (key) {
      return this.$t('vue.' + key.replace('contract_data.', ''))
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are getting three type of errors from the server (API response) **:**

- Unprocessable Entity
- can't be blank
- teammate_contract_end_after_company_contract

**Approach :** You can assign these errors in to language object like below.

```
const messages = {
    en: {
        error: {
            'code422Msg': 'Unprocessable Entity',
            'requiredFieldMsg': 'can't be blank',
            'endDateMsg': 'teammate_contract_end_after_company_contract'
        }
    }
}
```

Now, Instead of returning the error text from API, you can return `error.code422Msg`, `error.requiredFieldMsg`, `error.endDateMsg` based on the validations.

And then finally, translate these dot notation strings in template or in script using `$t('error.code422Msg')`, `$t('error.requiredFieldMsg')`, `$t('error.endDateMsg')`

Hope it will work! Thanks